# Mobx-state-tree use mobx reactions inside the tree - Good or Bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I have an article which is a mobx-state-tree object and I am using it in a react application.

This is an action inside my tree

```
setId(id: string) {
  self.id = id

  this.updateProduct()
},
```

And the event

```
 <input
  value={comp.productId}
  onChange={(e) => comp.setId(e.target.value)}
/>
```

The problem is that `this.updateProduct()` runs on every change and makes an async call after each key press.

I would like to take advantage of the mobx reactions and use something like

```
reaction(
() => ({
  id: this.id
}),
() => {
  this.updateProduct()
}, {
  delay: 500 // this is the key thing
})
```

I've found delay to be pretty useful in such cases so I would like to use them inside the tree.

Is it a good practice to add reactions inside the mobx-state-tree? If yes, where is the correct place to use the reactions?

I can define the reaction inside the react component but them it will be outside of the tree. Is it a good practice to be outside of the tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `afterCreate` and `beforeDestroy` actions to create and dispose a reaction.

**Example**

```
.actions(self => {
  let dispose;

  const afterCreate = () => {
    dispose = reaction(
      () => ({
        id: this.id
      }),
      () => {
        this.updateProduct();
      },
      {
        delay: 500
      }
    );
  };

  const beforeDestroy = dispose;

  return {
    afterCreate,
    beforeDestroy
  };
});
```

You can also use the `addDisposer` helper so there is no need for manual cleanup in `beforeDestroy` if you prefer.

```
.actions(self => {
  function afterCreate() {
    const dispose = reaction(
      () => ({
        id: this.id
      }),
      () => {
        this.updateProduct();
      },
      {
        delay: 500
      }
    );

    addDisposer(self, dispose);
  }

  return {
    afterCreate
  };
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue, I have tested the code, seem like, after 0.5s it will call updateProduct() even the product is changing in the client